# Azure SQL Vertical Elastic Query tutorial error

Tags: sql, azure, elasticsearch

I am following the Microsoft tutorial 
for vertical elastic querying at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started-vertical

I entered the code as follows:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'redacted'; 
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ElasticDBQueryCred
WITH IDENTITY = 'redacted',
SECRET = 'redacted';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc WITH
    (TYPE = RDBMS,
    LOCATION = 'redactedazure.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME = 'Redacted_Staging',
    CREDENTIAL = ElasticDBQueryCred,
    );

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[CustomerInformation]
( [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [CustomerName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [Company] [varchar](50) NOT NULL)
WITH
( DATA_SOURCE = MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc)

SELECT OrderInformation.CustomerID, OrderInformation.OrderId, CustomerInformation.CustomerName, CustomerInformation.Company
FROM OrderInformation
INNER JOIN CustomerInformation
ON CustomerInformation.CustomerID = OrderInformation.CustomerID;
```

However, I am getting the following errors:

Msg 46823, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Error retrieving data from redactedazure.database.windows.net.Redacted_Staging.  The underlying error message received was: 'Error retrieving data from redactedazure.database.windows.net.Redacted_Staging.  The underlying error message received was: 'Error retrieving data from... (repeats)

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure you possess ALTER ANY EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE permission?

ALTER ANY EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE permissions are needed to refer to the underlying data source.

You can see: [Vertical partitioning - cross-database queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview#vertical-partitioning---cross-database-queries)

[image]

Hope this can helps you.